# Can a curve be added in GIMP as a layer?

Tags: gimp

The colours in a GIMP image can be modified by using the curve tool. When I apply the curve tool, the original values are forgotten. Is is possible to apply the curve tool as a layer filter so that the curve that I am using as a filter and the original image pixel values are stored for later modification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, no. In Photoshop, this is called "adjustment layers" and it is one of the [key photographic features Gimp currently lacks](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/7691/1943).

We have a question about how to work around this, here: [How to create the equivalent of an Adjustment Layer in an editor that does not support it?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/13383/1943) (but I'm afraid the answers aren't going to be very helpful).

You can find "filter layers" on the [Gimp roadmap](http://wiki.gimp.org/index.php/Roadmap), somewhere in the middle of the top 15 high-priority features, but unfortunately it looks like no one is actually working on it and it's scheduled for only the vague *"Future"*.