# What is the Orton Effect and how can I apply it to digital photographs?

Tags: post-processing, photoshop, digital, film

I have heard of a photographic effect known as the 'Orton Effect'.

Can anyone tell me what the effect is, what its history is and how I would create it in both film and on my digital SLR?

Comment: Nik Color Effects has a filter that does this quite well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Orton Effect is an image-processing technique resulting in a high-contrast look with a slightly "glowing" appearance. It started as an analogue technique made from two slide exposures of the same scene - one sharp and one soft - but nowadays it's more commonly done digitally. You can find [plenty of examples on Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/search/?q=orton%20effect).

A basic recipe for doing this in Photoshop (or similar image-editing software) is as follows:

1. Create a **duplicate layer** (so you have two copies of the image, stacked one directly on top of the other).
2. Set the blend mode of the top layer to **Overlay**.
3. Apply a **Gaussian blur** to the top layer - the required amount will depend on the size and subject matter of the image, so experiment.
4. Tweak the **opacity** of the top layer to taste: somewhere around 50-80% should do it but again it'll depend on the image and how pronounced you want the effect to be.

Comment: I forgot one bit: the Overlay blend will often result in quite a dark image, so you may want to slightly over-expose your original shot (either in camera or in post-processing).

Comment: The image seems to have disappeared from Flickr, could you replace it?

Answer (score 9):

According to Michael Orton, the originator of the method, he used this to imitate watercolor paintings when using slide film. It involves overlaying of a sharp, overexposed image with an out-of-focus version of the same image.

This can be done in Photoshop or similar by mixing image and a blurred version of it. Playing with the transparency levels gives you control over the outcome.

My understanding is that while the in-focus image gives the detail, the blurred image gets the bleeding of the water paints on the canvas.

You can read about it directly from the man himself [here](http://www.michaelortonphotography.com/ortoneffect.html).

Comment: Is overexposure needed in digital case as well?

Comment: @Imre - I don't really know, but my understanding is that the overexposure was required to compensate for stacking of several slide layers. In digital blending this happens automatically, so I assume this is not necessary per-se, but may add to some "glowing" or brightness effect, as per Mark's answer example.

Answer (score 3):

The technique I've seen for the Orton Effect in photoshop uses two duplicate layers.  The first is set to screen, and creates a very light version of the image.  The second is blurred and set to multiply blend mode.  Compared to Mark Whitaker's version, this recipe will tend to produce a lighter, more ethereal effect.

Precise steps, a downloadable action, and a podcast with Michael Orton here: [Orton Imagery – The Orton Effect – Interview with Michael Orton and Darwin Wiggett](http://www.photography.ca/blog/2009/06/03/67-orton-imagery-the-orton-effect-interview-with-michael-orton-and-darwin-wiggett/)