# How to make the post-processing effect used by Hannes Cmarits in his "attracting curves III2"?

Tags: post-processing, photoshop, reverse-engineering

I like these [photography post-processing effects](http://fineartamerica.com/featured/attracting-curves-iii2-hannes-cmarits.html).

Could someone explain how to make them.

Comment: Can you describe the effect in words a little bit, so that future visitors with the same question might find it via a search engine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original photo is a vintage car in the midst of a fairly busy scene; probably a street in New York. To the left, what's undoubtedly an iconic NYC yellow cab. There's people around, possibly people gawking at the car or maybe just minding their business going down the sidewalk. The photographer didn't like the busyness of the composition, or the look of the people, and so decided to blur the surroundings away. The car was masked out so it wouldn't be affected, and then some distortion/blur filter was applied. I'm not sure exactly what filter was used, but it's something like [this CrossBlur effect](http://www.filterforge.com/filters/294.html). This leaves an interesting texture and a hint of the original scene.

That didn't come out right in the background visible through the car's windows; I'm not sure if that was included in the filter and didn't work very well due to the small area of that section, or if it was just badly cloned in after the fact. Or on second look, maybe it just was entirely unmodified: it looks like you can see the hood of a modern car behind. The license plate was probably blurred-out manually.

Anyway, now it's fine art.

Comment: and why do you answer for "unreal", from your point of view, question? :)

Comment: @garik, I don't think this type of questio is inherently bad, but as I commented, it _really_ helps if you can describe the effect you see in text. Otherwise, it leaves us guessing at what you mean rather than answering the real question.

Comment: Anyway, while the idea of blur and sharpness mixed in one image _may_ be inspired by the [Orton Effect](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14826/what-is-the-orton-effect-and-how-can-i-apply-it-to-digital-photographs), both the technique used and the result are quite different. I really don't think that's what the photographer was going for.